# evitar que se repita información que viene de una lista con react

Tags: reactjs

Estoy pasándole una lista a mi componente de react HotelsizeFilter, es una lista de hoteles, y en la propiedad rooms trae cuantas camas tiene cada hotel, de acuerdo a las condiciones se sabe si el hotel es pequeño, mediano o grande, y quiero poner hotel grande, hotel mediano y hotel pequeño como opciones del select pero obviamente me trae el resultado de todos los hoteles como lo muestra la fotografía, pero yo solo quiero 3, como podría hacer para que no me muestre valores repetidos.

Gracias por la ayuda.

```
 import {React, useState} from 'react';
    
    const HotelsizeFilter = (props) => {
    
       
        return (
            <>
            <select name="" id="">
                <option selected disabled>Cualquier tamaño</option>
                {
                    props.hotelsData.map((size)=>{4
                        if(size.rooms > 0 && size.rooms <= 10){
                            return <option value={size.rooms}>Hotel pequeño</option>
                        }else if(size.rooms > 10 && size.rooms <= 20){
                            return <option value={size.rooms}>Hotel mediano</option>
                        }else if(size.rooms > 20){
                            return <option value={size.rooms}>Hotel grande</option>
                        }
                    })
                }
            </select>
            </>
        );
    }
    
    export default HotelsizeFilter;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Porque no asignar estas 3 opciones de forma estática, es decir configurar un `UI State`; se supone que yo como usuario en ese paso, apenas voy a buscar hoteles con esa característica. Una ves que el usuario seleccione el tipo de hotel, ya se podría hacer un filtro con esa característica sobre `hotelsData`, saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te dicen en comentarios, seguramente lo ideal sería definirlo de forma estática. De todas formas, si quieres que esos valores sean calculados, lo mejor sería hacerlo en el momento de recuperar el `hotelsData`. Podrías setear en ese momento un array de `strings` con los distintos valores y luego hacer un Set para obtener solamente los valores únicos. Ese cálculo podrías hacerlo en el momento de pasárselo por `props` a tu componente hijo (o bien setearlo en otro estado en caso de que quieras modificar su valor por lo que sea). Te dejo [aquí](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5vjyve) un pequeño ejemplo

Comment: Muy práctico el uso del objeto `set` para eliminar repeticiones de un arreglo.